# How to put into a cell a product of another cell with a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to vba and I've been trying to make the following code work:

```
convert = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets("Convert").Range("C:C"), _
      Sheets("Convert").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Vista").Range("L8"), _
      Sheets("Convert").Range("D:D"), Sheets("Vista").Range("C2"), _
      Sheets("Convert").Range("E:E"), Sheets("Vista").Range("AC4"))

Sheets("series").Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=RC[-8]*"&convert&"
```

What I'm trying to do, is to put into a variable the result of a SUMIF formula, and use that same value to multiply it with the value of another cell.

It gives me an error of "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you have extra quotes. Try: `Sheets("series").Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*"&convert

Comment: Still gives the same error, after taking the extra quote out

Comment: Does the function work if you type it directly in the cell? (use the value of the variable and not the variable when testing this)

Comment: Maybe a long shot... maybe the sheet name "series" is incorrect with small **s**. @VBasic2008. You are right. I recreated the situation again and it worked... so I guess my excel was just weird first time. Thanks to point out :)!!. Then I think my previous answer didn't bring anything valuable, so I deleted it.

Comment: No, the sheet name is correct. The problem is with the variable. When I put in the variable it gives me the error mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Arrays Again

### The Eliminator

```
Sub Eliminator()

Dim convert As Long

'Convert = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets("Convert").Range("C:C"), _
      Sheets("Convert").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Vista").Range("L8"), _
      Sheets("Convert").Range("D:D"), Sheets("Vista").Range("C2"), _
      Sheets("Convert").Range("E:E"), Sheets("Vista").Range("AC4"))

'e.g.
convert = 1000
Sheets("series").Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*" & convert

End Sub
```

### Blah, Blah...

Now that we have concluded that the 'Convert' line is causing the error...
Since I use Excel 2003 and you have written the formula correctly, I can only guess that since SumIfs is something like an array formula it can't always be used successfully in VBA, or maybe never!? if you have error values in cells, there might be the solution, because VBA treats them as 'VBA Errors'.

### The 'SumIfsless' Solution

So I provided another solution without using SumIfs. You can run it from VBA or any other worksheet. The 'str1' commented lines are for debugging purposes. You can uncomment them and see some 'subtotals' in the Immediate window.

```
Sub SumIfsArray()
'Variables
  'Objects
  Dim oRng As Range 'Range of the Sum Column (To Calculate First and Last Row)
  'Arrays
  Dim arrRngAddress As Variant 'Compare Addresses
  Dim arrWs As Variant 'Worksheet Names
  Dim arrCol As Variant 'Three Lookup Columns and the Sum Column
  Dim arrRng As Variant 'Values of the Compare Addresses
  Dim arrRanges As Variant 'The Ranges of the Four Columns
  Dim arrArrays As Variant 'The Values of the Four Columns
  'Other
  Dim iCol As Integer 'Columns Counter
  Dim lngFirst As Long 'First Usable Row of Data
  Dim lngLast As Long 'Last Usable Row of Data
  Dim lngRows As Long 'Number of Rows of Usable Data
  Dim lngRow As Long 'Rows Counter
  Dim lngSum As Long 'Sum of Values
  Dim blnArr As Boolean 'True if all three conditions are met.

'                'Debug Variables
'                Const c1 As String = "," 'Debug String Column Separator
'                Const r1 As String = vbCr 'Debug String Row Separator
'                Dim i1 As Integer 'Debug String Column Counter
'                Dim lo1 As Long 'Debug String Rows Counter
'                Dim str1 As String 'Debug String Concatenator


'Initialize
  arrRngAddress = Array("L8", "C2", "AC4")
  arrWs = Array("Convert", "Vista", "series")
  arrCol = Array("A:A", "D:D", "E:E", "C:C")

'Program
  ReDim arrRng(1 To 3)
  With Worksheets(arrWs(1)) 'Worksheet "Vista"
    For iCol = 1 To 3
      arrRng(iCol) = .Range(arrRngAddress(iCol - 1)).Value
    Next
  End With

'            str1 = "The Values"
'            For i1 = 1 To 3: str1 = str1 & r1 & Space(1) & arrRng(i1)
'            Next: Debug.Print str1

  With Worksheets(arrWs(0)) 'Worksheet "Convert"
    'Number of 'usable' rows of data
    Set oRng = .Range(arrCol(3))

    With oRng
      If .Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
        lngFirst = 1
       Else
        lngFirst = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
      End If
      lngLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    Set oRng = Nothing
    lngRows = lngLast - lngFirst + 1

    'Array of Ranges
    ReDim arrRanges(1 To 4)
    For iCol = 1 To 4
      arrRanges(iCol) = Range(Cells(lngFirst, Range(arrCol(iCol - 1)).Column), _
          Cells(lngLast, Range(arrCol(iCol - 1)).Column)).Address
    Next

'            str1 = "The Ranges"
'            For i1 = 1 To 4: str1 = str1 & r1 & Space(1) & arrRanges(i1)
'            Next: Debug.Print str1

    'Array of Arrays
    ReDim arrArrays(1 To 4)
    For iCol = 1 To 4
      arrArrays(iCol) = .Range(arrRanges(iCol)).Value
    Next
  End With

'            str1 = "Values of Ranges" & r1 & Space(1) & "A,D,E,C"
'            For lo1 = 1 To lngRows: str1 = str1 & r1 & Space(1): For i1 = 1 To 4
'                If i1 <> 1 Then
'                  str1 = str1 & c1 & arrArrays(i1)(lo1, 1)
'                 Else: str1 = str1 & arrArrays(i1)(lo1, 1)
'                End If: Next: Next: Debug.Print str1

  'Sum of Values
  For lngRow = 1 To lngRows
    For iCol = 1 To 3
      If arrArrays(iCol)(lngRow, 1) = arrRng(iCol) Then
        blnArr = True
       Else
        blnArr = False
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
    If blnArr = True Then
      lngSum = lngSum + arrArrays(4)(lngRow, 1)
    End If
  Next

'            str1 = "The Sum": str1 = str1 & r1 & Space(1) & lngSum

'Output
  'Worksheet "series"
  Worksheets(arrWs(2)).Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]*" & lngSum

End Sub
```

P.S. I **never ever** use variable names with the **same** name as a worksheet name in the same workbook.